# Use Justfile to Modify Calling Shell

Tags: just

Is there a way to call/use `just` to modify the calling shell?

I have a project that currently uses `just` for most things that a developer would want to do. E.g. `just build`, `just test`, etc. But to setup the local environment for developing at the moment they have to run `source setup.sh`. I would love to be able to set up the Justfile so that I can have users run `just setup` or similar, and have Just modify the users shell for them.